# Compilation error in Merge Sort in Haskell

Tags: haskell, mergesort

I was writing Merge Sort in Haskell and it is giving a strange error:

```
Couldn't match expected type '[a0] -> Int' with actual type '[Int]'
```

Code is:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int] 
f l 
  |length l == 1 = l    
  |length l == 2 = if head l > last l then reverse l else l
  |otherwise = myappend ( take ( div length l 2 )  l )  ( drop ( div length l 2 ) l )

myappend  :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
myappend l [] = l
myappend [] l = l
myappend ( x : xs ) (y : ys) = if x > y then y : x : myappend xs ys else x : y : myappend ys xs
```

Comment: your algorithm is broken, and your `myappend` is wrong. consider merging `[1,2,5]` and `[3,4]` with it. --- also, next time please show your error message in full.

Comment: I have fixed it. I couldn't check my program with some data since it wasn't compiling. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `div length l 2` part. Here you're giving `div` 3 arguments: `length`, `l` and 2. Instead, you should have written `div (length l) 2`.

Comment: Thanks. Can someone suggest me "how" Haskell reads a statement? My instructor told me that the function operation has the highest precendence.

Comment: It has. But also keep in mind that functions are data. Thus, function application happens only if the function is the first word after an operator

Comment: Finally, have a look at http://learnyouahaskell.com/ book. It will get you quickly up to speed with Haskell.

Comment: Yes, and it's left associated, so `div length l 2` is in fact `((div length) l) 2`.